# Pointer with cin implementation issue

Tags: c++

I'm a new bie to CPP. I'm trying to use `pointer` and `cin` combination which is giving strange result.

```
int *array;
int numOfElem = 0;
cout << "\nEnter number of  elements in array : ";  
cin  >> numOfElem;
array = new (nothrow)int[numOfElem];

if(array != 0)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < numOfElem; index++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter " << index << " value";
        cin >> *array++;
    }

    cout << "\n values are : " ;
    for(int index = 0; index < numOfElem; index++)
    {
        cout << *(array+index) << ",";
    }
}else
{
    cout << "Memory cant be allocated :(";
}
```

The out put is

[image]

What the problem with my  code ?

Regards,
Sha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are advancing the pointer, `array`, in the first loop:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numOfElem; index++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter " << index << " value";
    cin >> *array++;
}
```

And then you pretend you are using the original, unmodified pointer in the second loop:

```
cout << "\n values are : " ;
for(int index = 0; index < numOfElem; index++)
{
    cout << *(array+index) << ",";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Is there any method to make the pointer point to first position again after the first loop?

Comment: Subtract `numOfElem` from it since you're adding `numOfElem` ones to it.

Answer (score 3):

The `array++` inside the loop increments the pointer, so by the time you're done with the first loop, `array` will point outside the originally allocated array.

Just do

```
cin >> *(array+index);
```

or simply

```
cin >> array[index];
```